How to find a primitive element to split a prime $p$ in a number field
The Dedekind-Kummer Theorem allows one to split primes in a number field $K$ by splitting the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ modulo $p$, where $\alpha$ is a primitive element for $K$ contained in the ring of integers. Unfortunately, we have to satisfy the condition that the prime being split is coprime to the the conductor of the order generated by $\alpha$.
There are a few places where it is claimed that for a particular prime $p$, we can always get around this obstruction, i.e. that for any $p$ there exists a $\theta$ such that the order generated by that $\theta$ has index not divisible by $p$ (see here Remark 0.0.2, for example). I've had a hard time tracking down a proof, so:
Given a prime $p$ and a number field $K$, how do we find a primitive element for $K$ such that $p \nmid [\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$?

The question you posed at the end has no general affirmative answer: there are $K$ and $p$ where $p \mid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$ for all $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$ such that $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$.  The first example ever found of this phenomenon, with $p = 2$, is due to Dedekind: when $K = \mathbf Q(\gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is a root of $x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 8$, Dedekind proved that $2 \mid [\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$ for all $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K - \mathbf Z$.  This is shown in the proof of Theorem 1.1 here, and later sections there give infinitely many similar examples.
Taking the base field to be $\mathbf Q$ for simplicity, the Remark 0.0.2 that you link to is not actually discussing the existence of a primitive element $\beta$ such that the index of $\mathbf Z[\beta]$ in the ring of integers upstairs is prime to $p$, but about the existence of a $\beta$ whose conductor (meaning the conductor of $\mathbf Z[\beta]$) is prime to $p$. But this is not always true!
Example.  Suppose $L$ is a cubic field in which $2$ splits completely. (The field $K$ I mentioned above is such a field.) Assume there is some $\beta \in \mathcal O_L - \mathbf Z$ such that the conductor of $\mathbf Z[\beta]$ is coprime to $2\mathcal O_L$. Let $p_\beta(x) \in \mathbf Z[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbf Q$, so $p_\beta(x)$ is a monic cubic over $\mathbf Z$. Remark 0.0.2 says the way $2\mathcal O_L$ decomposes into prime ideals in $\mathcal O_L$ matches the way $p_\beta(x) \bmod 2$ decomposes into irreducibles in $(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)[x]$. But since $2$ splits completely in $L$, $p_\beta(x) \bmod 2$ would have to split completely over $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, but that would mean there are at least three monic linear polynomials in $(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)[x]$ and that's not true: the only such polynomials are $x$ and $x+1$.
Remark. The invalid remark you cite probably has its source as an incorrectly posed exercise in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, which was the topic of an earlier MSE question here and you'll see the cubic example with $2$ being used there as well to show the Neukirch exercise is not right as written.
The bottom line is that you can't expect to have some rule that explains how every prime decomposes in every number field purely in terms of the irreducible factorization of some polynomials mod $p$, because $p$ might split completely in a number field of degree $n > p$ (like 2 splitting completely in a cubic field) and there are not $n$ different monic linear polynomials mod $p$ when $n > p$.
There is a $p$-adic method that can give you information about how $p$ decomposes in a number field $K$.  Suppose $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$ and let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf Q$.  Then the number of primes over $p$ in $K$ is the number of different monic irreducible factors of $m(x)$ in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$ and the products $e_if_i$ at the various primes over $p$ in $K$ equal the degrees of the irreducible factors of $m(x)$ in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$. (Note this is not saying what the individual $e_i$'s and $f_i$'s are, only what their products $e_if_i$ are.) In particular, $p$ splits completely in $K$ if and only if $m(x)$ splits completely in $\mathbf Q_p[x]$.
